# Adjust the org chart line to be from/to the side of the node versus top or bottom for organization chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am using the Organization Chart and want to change the start of a line to be from a different place of the node. An example fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/markjjordan/oL19jfwv/70/.

The source code is as follows:

```
var nodes = [
            {
        id: '001.b001.b004',
        //column: 1,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-30%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b003',
        //column: 2,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-30%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b002',
        //column: 3,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-30%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b001.b004',
        //column: 4,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-15%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b001.b003',
        //column: 5,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-15%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b001.b002',
        //column: 6,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-15%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b001.b001',
        //column: 7,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-15%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b001',
        //column: 8,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-30%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001.b005',
        //column: 0,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-30%',
      }      
      ,
            {
        id: '001.b001',
        //column: 9,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-45%',
      } 
      ,
      {
        id: '001',
        //column: 10,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-60%',
        color: 'orange'
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001',
        //column: 11,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-45%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.005',
        //column: 12,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-30%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.001',
        //column: 13,
        //width: 200,
        offset: '-30%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.001.001',
        //width: 200,
        //column: 14,
        offset: '-15%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.001.002',
        //width: 200,
        //column: 15,
        offset: '-15%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.001.003',
        //width: 200,
        //column: 16,
        offset: '-15%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.001.004',
        //width: 200,
        //column: 17,
        offset: '-15%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.002',
        //width: 200,
        //column: 18,
        offset: '-30%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.003',
        //width: 200,
        //column: 19,
        offset: '-30%',
      }
      , 
      {
        id: '001.001.004',
        //width: 200,
        //column: 20,
        offset: '-30%',
      }
    ]
   ;

var counter = 0;
nodes.forEach(function(element) {
  //console.log(element);
  element.width = 200;
  element.column = counter++;
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    height: 2000,
    //width: 800,
    inverted: true
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Org Chart'
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'organization',
    name: 'Highsoft',
    keys: ['from', 'to'],
    nodePadding: 5,
    hangingIndent: 10,
    data: [
      ['001', '001.001'],
      ['001.001', '001.001.005'],
      ['001.001', '001.001.001'],
            ['001.001.001', '001.001.001.001'],
            ['001.001.001', '001.001.001.002'],
            ['001.001.001', '001.001.001.003'],
            ['001.001.001', '001.001.001.004'],
      ['001.001', '001.001.002'],
      ['001.001', '001.001.003'],
      ['001.001', '001.001.004'],

      ['001', '001.b001'],
      ['001.b001', '001.b001.b001'],
            ['001.b001.b001', '001.b001.b001.b001'],
            ['001.b001.b001', '001.b001.b001.b002'],
            ['001.b001.b001', '001.b001.b001.b003'],
            ['001.b001.b001', '001.b001.b001.b004'],
      ['001.b001', '001.b001.b002'],
      ['001.b001', '001.b001.b003'],
      ['001.b001', '001.b001.b004'],
      ['001.b001', '001.b001.b005'],

    ],

    nodes: nodes,
    colorByPoint: false,
    color: '#007ad0',
    dataLabels: {
      color: 'white'
    },
    borderColor: 'white',
    nodeWidth: 65
  }],
  tooltip: {
    outside: true
  },
  exporting: {
    allowHTML: true,
    sourceWidth: 800,
    sourceHeight: 600
  }

});
```

All blue nodes above the orange one have a "from" reference for the orange node and a "to" reference for the blue node in the data parameter of HighCharts… I needed to do this because I want everything above the orange node to have multiple parents.

What I'd like as far as the lines go is to have lines coming from or to a blue node to be on the left side instead of the top or bottom as in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it simply by wrapping the `Highcharts.seriesTypes.organization.prototype.translateLink` method and changing the way links path is created. I've prepared an example for you where a new `layout = "custom"` is added.

**Code:**

```
(function(H) {

  H.seriesTypes.organization.prototype.translateLink = function(point) {
    var fromNode = point.fromNode,
      toNode = point.toNode,
      series = point.series,
      layout = toNode.layout,
      crisp = Math.round(this.options.linkLineWidth) % 2 / 2,
      x1 = Math.floor(
        fromNode.shapeArgs.x + fromNode.shapeArgs.width
      ) + crisp,
      y1 = Math.floor(
        fromNode.shapeArgs.y + fromNode.shapeArgs.height / 2
      ) + crisp,
      x2 = Math.floor(toNode.shapeArgs.x) + crisp,
      y2 = Math.floor(
        toNode.shapeArgs.y + toNode.shapeArgs.height / 2
      ) + crisp,
      xMiddle,
      hangingIndent = this.options.hangingIndent,
      toOffset = toNode.options.offset,
      percentOffset = /%$/.test(toOffset) && parseInt(toOffset, 10),
      inverted = this.chart.inverted,
      isEven = fromNode.linksFrom.length % 2 === 0,
      lastToNodeId =
      fromNode.linksFrom[fromNode.linksFrom.length - 1].to,
      linkBranchOffset = H.defined(fromNode.linkBranchOffset) ?
      fromNode.linkBranchOffset : undefined,
      prevOffset = 'prevLinkBranchOffset' + fromNode.column,
      middleNode1,
      middleNode2,
      directionIndicator,
      linkDirection,
      linkCorrection,
      branchOffset,
      d;

    if (inverted) {
      x1 -= fromNode.shapeArgs.width;
      x2 += toNode.shapeArgs.width;
    }
    xMiddle = Math.floor(
      x2 +
      (inverted ? 1 : -1) *
      (this.colDistance - this.nodeWidth) / 2
    ) + crisp;

    // Put the link on the side of the node when an offset is given. HR
    // node in the main demo.
    if (
      percentOffset &&
      (percentOffset >= 50 || percentOffset <= -50)
    ) {
      xMiddle = x2 = Math.floor(
        x2 + (inverted ? -0.5 : 0.5) * toNode.shapeArgs.width
      ) + crisp;
      y2 = toNode.shapeArgs.y;
      if (percentOffset > 0) {
        y2 += toNode.shapeArgs.height;
      }
    }

    if (toNode.hangsFrom === fromNode) {
      if (this.chart.inverted) {
        y1 = Math.floor(
          fromNode.shapeArgs.y +
          fromNode.shapeArgs.height -
          hangingIndent / 2
        ) + crisp;
        y2 = toNode.shapeArgs.y + toNode.shapeArgs.height;
      } else {
        y1 = Math.floor(
          fromNode.shapeArgs.y +
          hangingIndent / 2
        ) + crisp;

      }
      xMiddle = x2 = Math.floor(
        toNode.shapeArgs.x + toNode.shapeArgs.width / 2
      ) + crisp;
    }

    if (layout === 'custom') {
        d = this.curvedPath([
        [x1, y1],
        [xMiddle - toNode.nodeHeight / 2 - 10, y1],
        [xMiddle - toNode.nodeHeight / 2 - 10, y2]
      ], this.options.linkRadius);
    } else {
      d = this.curvedPath([
        [x1, y1],
        [xMiddle, y1],
        [xMiddle, y2],
        [x2, y2]
      ], this.options.linkRadius);
    }

    point.plotY = 1;
    point.shapeType = 'path';
    point.shapeArgs = {
      d: d
    };
  }
})(Highcharts)
```

**Demo:** (open on screen width > 800px)

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/02raLmuo/